# Avoid stopping on error when in debug mode Access 97

Tags: ms-access, debugging, vba, ms-access-97

When I enter into debug mode in Access 97, the program will halt on any error, even if that error is occurring after `On Error Resume Next`.

I have a function that tests if an element `key` is in a `Collection Col` using

```
On Error Resume Next
var = Col.Item(key)  'Here the error is raised, and makes debug mode useless
...
InConnection = Not (Err.Number = 5)
```

This works well in production, but it makes running the program in debug mode useless.

Is there a way to avoid that the program halts on certain errors in debug mode ?

As far as I could search there is no way to test if a key exist in a collection in Access 97, other than try and catch the error using the above method.

Comment: Generally, I loop over all items in a collection using a _For Each_ loop to test if an item exists (or use a dictionary instead). However, Access 97 is far before when I started programming. Is that not feasible for Access 97?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The `For Each` loop is possible, but this will create unnecessary nested loop and rais the time complexity to `O^2`. As for a `Dictionary` it does not seem to exist in Access 97.

Comment: `Dictionary` is a COM object (e.g. `Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.) . While looping does increase time complexity, I usually consider avoiding it premature optimization, looping over small collections generally doesn't take more than a couple of milliseconds, and avoiding it is messy since we don't have try...catch so it requires you to restate how you're handling errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA editor `Tools | Options...` on tab `General` activate `Break on Unhandled Errors` in `Error Trapping` group to silence OERN sections.

To check key existence in a `VBA.Collection` w/o error trapping one would need a specially crafted typelib, like the one discussed in [this forum thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?867363-Error-trapping-is-slow-in-compiled-applications).

Moreover, such typelib is a prerequisite for practicing the art of writing VBA code with `Break on All Errors` set -- a small feat in itself :-))

Comment: Thanks for the configuration tip. The use of a typelib is unfortunately not in reach of my knowledge :(